# reporting services with as400, cant select union

Tags: sql, database, reporting-services, ibm-midrange

I have a AS400 datasource. I want to union a select field. This union works with a SQL datasource, but not when using an ODBC driver connecting to the AS400.

I have a dropdown list parameter using this select statement:

```
SELECT a FROM tableb 
WHERE tableb.a = '0'
UNION   --The problem is the union.
SELECT '' AS Empty
```

End result should be: (but union will not work)

```
Empty
(a data)
(a data)
(a data)
.......etc
```

Error Message: Token  was not valid. Valid tokens: , From Into.

Comment: What's the UNION expression you're trying to use? What happens when you try?

Comment: It says  Token <End of statement> was not valid. Valid tokens: , From Into.

Comment: Try ending it with `SELECT '' AS Empty FROM sysibm.sysdummy1` http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sysibmsysdummy1table.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DB2/400 requires a `FROM` table:

```
SELECT a FROM tableb 
WHERE tableb.a = '0'
UNION   --The problem is the union.
SELECT '' AS Empty FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 3):

The SELECT after the UNION needs to be a complete SELECT statement.  That means you need a FROM clause.

```
UNION
SELECT 'Empty' as Empty
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```